# Javascript undefined attribute

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm new to Javascript and I got this:

I have a `GridView` with the following event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
  {
    c.Attributes.Add("full","false");
  }
}
```

And in my javascript I have an `onClick` event for every cell:

```
if(source.full="false")
{
  ...
  source.full="true";
}
else
{
  ...
  source.full="false";
}
```

Why is it that `source.full` is always `undefined` on the first click?

Comment: My guess is that what you're referencing in the JavaScript isn't the same thing you're setting in the original generating code.

Comment: have you tried source.getAttribute("full") instead of source.full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now used getAttribute and setAttribute instead like Simen said and it works very well.